# How to get channels in a segmentation mask in proper order?

Tags: python, mask, image-segmentation

I'm trying to solve a Covid-19 CT scan segmentation and I've tried segmenting images for myself using MedSeg free in-browser tool (https://www.medseg.ai/). I want to do that to increase my dataset which has 4 classes now: ground glass, consolidation, lung other and background. I found a dataset that contains only masks with ground glass labels. I wanted to segment lung other and background manually in them. However, these manually segmented masks have their channels in different order than my other images:

Manually segmented masks:

- 0 - background
- 1 - ground glass
- 2 - consolidation
- 3 - lung other

Proper masks:

- 0 - ground glass
- 1 - consolidation
- 2 - lung other
- 3 - background

When I download ready manually segmented mask, it's shape is (41, 512, 512). After downloading I add one dimension in the end, so it becomes (41, 512, 512, 1). Than I apply this function with this palette = [[0], [1], [2], [3]] (which works with my old dataset masks):

```
def mask_to_onehot(mask, palette):
"""
Converts a segmentation mask (H, W, C) to (H, W, K) where the last dim is a one
hot encoding vector, C is usually 1 or 3, and K is the number of class.
"""
semantic_map = []
for colour in palette:
    #print('colour',colour)
    equality = np.equal(mask, colour)
    #print('equality',equality)
    class_map = np.all(equality, axis=-1)
    semantic_map.append(class_map)
semantic_map = np.stack(semantic_map, axis=-1).astype(np.float32)
return torch.from_numpy(semantic_map)
```

And after that new masks become different from old ones. Could somebody please advice something? What is it that I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open settings menu in MedSeg (having opened your data with masks) and use the "change maskvalue from...to...". The following sequence should work for you: 0 to 5, then 1 to 0, then 2 to 1, then 3 to 2, then 5 to 3.

Something similar can of course also been done automatically in python, for example mask[mask==0]=5, mask[mask==1]=0 and so on.